# why the domain of $(2x - 3)^{e^{1/x - 1}}$ is $x > 3/2$

Tags: calculus, functions

I don't understand why the domain of $$(2x-3)^{e^{1/x-1}}$$ is $x > 3/2$. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: What? Your question is terribly formatted. How about using proper MathJax and show what you want to ask more clear?

Comment: Because you want $(2x-3)$ to be positive. It's hard to calculate non integer exponents of negative functions.

Comment: cmon guys, he's a first time user, go easy on him!

Comment: here's your answer, accept it as well if it suits you.

Comment: @Andrei more importantly, a negative quantity cannot be raised to an irrational exponent.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  It is not clear whether you meant $e^{\frac{1}{x} - 1}$ or $e^{\frac{1}{x - 1}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $e^{(1/x) -1}$ always returns some positive number (except at $x = 0$, where it is undefined), so you are trying to raise the number $(2x-3)$ to some positive real power. In general, real powers of negative numbers is undefined (e.g., $(-1)^{1/2}$ is not a real number), so in order for the function to be defined you want the quantity $2x-3$ to be positive, i.e., $2x-3 > 0$ or $x > 3/2$. [This graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wm84wguowb) also demonstrates that the domain is $x > 3/2$.

Answer (score 1):

For any exponential function whose exponent is positive, we require that the base be positive. Our base in this case is $2x-3$ thus we have

$$2x-3>0 \Rightarrow x > \frac{3}{2}$$

as needed. However, if we answer to be complex, we can omit this restriction of being positive. For example $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not a real number, it is a complex number, namely $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=  i \in \mathbb{C}$ that is if we allow the answer to be complex, as apposed to real.

Comment: The example you gave at the end of your answer doesn’t go well with your explanation, as the base is not complex, but the result is.  Did you mean to say “if we allow the result to be complex…”?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw Yes, meant to say if we allow the result to be complex. Edited.

Comment: ok thanks for the response

Comment: $(-1)^{1/2}$ is an ambiguous notation since each non-zero complex number has two distinct square roots. For $-1$ they are $i$ and $-i$.